# Are Transaction/Order/Trade ID/Numbers attached to the trade of a security sensitive information?

Tags: brokerage, security, privacy

Some brokerages display some Transaction/Order/Trade ID/Numbers that identifies or qualified a trade of a security (e.g., the purchase of some stock): is that sensitive information?

Example on TD Ameritrade:

[image]

Comment: Define "sensitive"

Comment: Let's make it broader and consider any personal information such as name.